# C# tcpclient not writing to socket...or maybe I'm not reading all of the response?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a C# console app to interface with a [PC Miler telnet server](https://support.pcmiler.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000076199-the-tcp-ip-interface). I managed to get this to work in powershell, but my C# code is not working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[]{"READY"};

    try
    {
        TcpClient Socket = new TcpClient("myServer", 8320);

        if (Socket.Connected) {
            NetworkStream netStream = Socket.GetStream();
            string PCMSResponse = "";

            // Check for the READY prompt
            if (netStream.CanRead) {
                int byteRead = 0;
                while (netStream.DataAvailable) {
                    byteRead = netStream.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, ReadBuffer.Length);
                    PCMSResponse += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReadBuffer, 0 , byteRead).Trim();
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot read from myServer");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Get New Trip
            if (netStream.CanWrite) {
                Byte[] PCMSCommandBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PCMSNewTrip");
                netStream.Write(PCMSCommandBuffer, 0 , PCMSCommandBuffer.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot write to myServer.");
            }
            if (netStream.CanRead) {
                int byteRead = 0;
                while (netStream.DataAvailable) {
                    byteRead = netStream.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, ReadBuffer.Length);
                    PCMSResponse += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReadBuffer, 0, byteRead).Trim();
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot read from myServer");
            }
            string[] ResponseArray = PCMSResponse.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int c = ResponseArray.Length - 2;
            string TripID = ResponseArray[c].Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("\0", "");
            Console.WriteLine(PCMSResponse);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server")
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
ALK PCMILER SERVER READY
pcmsnewtrip
53
READY
```

Actual output

```
ALK PCMILER SERVER READY
```

It seems like I am not actually writing to the server because if I were to write an invalid command to the server I would see an error like this:

```
ALK PCMILER SERVER READY
pmctripnew
NO SUCH FUNCTION
READY
```

I know I can write to the socket because I'm not getting my error message `Cannot write to myServer.`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. :(

Let me know if you'd also like to see the powershell code.

EDIT - If you're going to edit this post, at least keep the expected output **AS EXPECTED**! Changing the expected output changes the intent of the post. (EG, if I want apples but you edit my post to ask for oranges, I'm not going to get the correct answer.)

Comment: `netStream.DataAvailable` cannot look into the future (unless you have a time machine). It can indicate only whether there is **currently** data available (data is available in network-stack related receive buffers), but it is not capable of telling whether there is more data incoming within the next micro/milliseconds. You will have to keep attempting to read from the connection until you are either sure that all expected data has been received or you are sure some problem occured (i.e., like it took too much time waiting/hoping for incoming data).

Comment: If you send data of variable size, you would preferably let your sending party/side tell the receiving party/side first about the size of the data to be received, so the receiving party will know how much data it is expected to read from the connection/NetworkStream.

Comment: Also, you will likely need to call `netstream.Flush()` after your `netstream.Write(...)`

Comment: @FrankAlvaro, no, because NetworkStream.Flush() is a NOP...

Comment: ahhh, looky-there - good catch @elgonzo;

Comment: @elgonzo I see what you're saying. In a manual tests and the powershell script, the telnet server (which is local) returns 53 in ~10ms. Sleeping the thread for a full second is like 100 times longer than it should have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turns out to be that the `NetworkStream.Write` method does not end a string with a line terminator. As a result, when I wrote my `PCMSCommandBuffer` bytes to the stream, the command was never processed by the server (because its waiting for more of the command or the enter key to let it know you're done). My solution was to assign the stream to a `StreamWriter`. Then I can use the `WriteLine` method whichdoes send a line terminator.

```
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(netStream);
// Get New Trip
if (netStream.CanWrite) {
    Byte[] PCMSCommandBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PCMSNewTrip");
    //netStream.Write(PCMSCommandBuffer, 0 , PCMSCommandBuffer.Length);
    streamWriter.WriteLine("PCMSNewTrip");
    //netStream.Flush();
    streamWriter.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(PCMSCommandBuffer.Length + " PCMSNewTrip");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot write to EW-APP1.");
}
```